# \left/\right, \dots, amsmath, scrartcl are not compatible in TeX Live 2016

Tags: amsmath, texlive, koma-script

In TeX Live 2016 the following simple document fails to compile:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\[ \left( x+1 \right) \dots \left( x+8 \right). \]
\end{document}
```

Several errors are thrown, the first of which are:

```
! Argument of \zap@to@space has an extra }.
<inserted text> 
                \par 
l.6 \[ \left( x+1 \right) \dots \left
                                     ( x+8 \right). \]
? 
Runaway argument?
\left..........
! Paragraph ended before \zap@to@space was complete.
<to be read again> 
                   \par 
l.6 \[ \left( x+1 \right) \dots \left
                                     ( x+8 \right). \]
?
```

In addition, any of the following appear to cause the issue to go away:

- Changing from `scrartcl` to `article`
- Removing the line `\usepackage{amsmath}`
- Not using `\left(` and `\right)`
- Using an earlier version of TeXLive

I'm assuming this is a bug somewhere, but I'm not sure how to fix it (other than just manually using `\cdots` instead of `\dots`, I suppose). Does anyone have any ideas on how to make things behave the way they should?

[EDIT: to clarify, compiling with PDFLaTeX, on TeX Live 2016, Arch Linux.]

Comment: Om my TL2016 it compiles [just fine](http://i.imgur.com/GPBZC5b.png) using pdf/xe/lualatex.

Comment: How did you install Tex Live 2016 (link to steps followed if available) and on what operating system?

Comment: Can confirm on Ubuntu 1604.

Comment: there were some changes to the definition of `\dots` in `amsmath` for tex live 2016, required by some changes in luatex that i can't really explain.  but the changes were iterative, and your result may depend on when various files were installed on your system.  i'm pinging @DavidCarlisle to take a look at this; he knows the details.

Comment: Btw, it works fine if you load amsmath like this: `\documentclass[amsmath,11pt]{scrartcl}`

Comment: To clarify, TeX Live 2016 on Arch Linux, compiling with PDFLaTeX. Also, the comment by JPi works for me as well.

Comment: This is fixed in the current amsmath, so if you update it should be fine

Comment: @JPi `scrartcl` doesn't appear to have an `amsmath` option, so that's just same as not specifying amsmath isn't it?

Comment: Yes, i guess you're right...